# WPF XAML editor always says Dictionary with custom key type is not a collection

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to clear up some squigglies in our project's XAML. The issue I'm facing is that we use dictionaries that use a custom type as the key rather than string.
This works fine at runtime, but the XAML editor squigglies the uses of them with the error:

> Type 'Dictionary`2' is not a Collection

Example:

```xml
<Window x:Class="DictionaryCustomKey.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DictionaryCustomKey"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800" Height="450"
        DataContext="{x:Static local:MainWindow.TheData}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StringKeyDictionary}" />
        <TextBlock Text="String First is:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringKeyDictionary[First]}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyKeyDictionary}" />
        <TextBlock Text="MyKey First is:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyKeyDictionary[First]}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The very last instance of "First" is squigglied.

Here's the codebehind where I try everything I can imagine to make the editor happy that the key type "MyKey" is suitable as a Dictionary key:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;

namespace DictionaryCustomKey
{
    public class Data
    {
        public class MyKeyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
            {
                return sourceType == typeof(string);
            }

            public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
            {
                return sourceType == typeof(string);
            }

            public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
            {
                if (value is string)
                {
                    return new MyKey((string)value);
                }
                return null;
            }

            public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (destinationType == typeof(string))
                {
                    return ((MyKey)value).String;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(MyKeyTypeConverter))]
        public class MyKey : IComparable, IComparable<MyKey>, IComparable<string>, IEquatable<MyKey>, IEquatable<string>, IConvertible
        {
            public MyKey(string stringKey)
            {
                m_String = stringKey;
            }

            public static implicit operator MyKey(string v)
            {
                return new MyKey(v);
            }

            public static implicit operator string(MyKey v)
            {
                return v.m_String;
            }

            public String String => m_String;

            private String m_String;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is MyKey)
                {
                    return ((MyKey)obj) == this;
                }
                if (obj is string)
                {
                    return ((string)obj) == this.String;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public bool Equals(MyKey other)
            {
                return this == other;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return String.GetHashCode();
            }

            public int CompareTo(object obj)
            {
                return String.CompareTo(obj);
            }

            public int CompareTo(MyKey other)
            {
                return String.CompareTo(other);
            }

            public int CompareTo(string other)
            {
                return String.CompareTo(other);
            }

            public bool Equals(string other)
            {
                return String.Equals(other);
            }

            public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
            {
                return String.GetTypeCode();
            }

            public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToBoolean(provider);
            }

            public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToChar(provider);
            }

            public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToSByte(provider);
            }

            public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToByte(provider);
            }

            public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToInt16(provider);
            }

            public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToUInt16(provider);
            }

            public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToInt32(provider);
            }

            public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToUInt32(provider);
            }

            public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToInt64(provider);
            }

            public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToUInt64(provider);
            }

            public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToSingle(provider);
            }

            public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToDouble(provider);
            }

            public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToDecimal(provider);
            }

            public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToDateTime(provider);
            }

            public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return String.ToString(provider);
            }

            public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
            {
                return ((IConvertible)String).ToType(conversionType, provider);
            }

            public static bool operator ==(MyKey lhs, MyKey rhs)
            {
                return lhs.String == rhs.String;
            }

            public static bool operator !=(MyKey lhs, MyKey rhs)
            {
                return !(lhs == rhs);
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> StringKeyDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"First", "zero"},
            {"Second", "one"}
        };
        public Dictionary<MyKey, object> MyKeyDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<MyKey, object>
        {
            {new MyKey("First"), "zero"},
            {new MyKey("Second"), "one"}
        };
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static public Data TheData { get; set; } = new Data();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to work.

**Edit**: An answer is given that makes the squiggly go away, but it reveals there is actually a worse problem: squiggly or not, the designer has trouble displaying the binding: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/848331/visual-studio-must-be-restarted-after-every-build.html

Comment: You should be able to use any type as a key of a dictionary and it's the viewmodel will be using that data. But making the viewmodel a static property of mainwindow would widely be considered bad practice.  Have you considered making your viewmodel a separate class and  instantiating that in the xaml?

Comment: We don't do that normally, that's just for the purposes of making this example.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the XAML editor. Using nested element syntax doesn't have the error:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyKeyDictionary[First]" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I would recommend reporting it through the Visual Studio feedback tool.

Comment: Interesting, using nested element syntax does indeed make the squiggly go away.
While playing with your fix I noticed that changing the type of the Dictionary property from Dictionary<MyKey, object> to IDictionary also makes the squiggly go away.
But I notice that there is a worse problem whether using that syntax or not - the designer fails to show the binding after building the solution unless you restart visual studio and every build.
It seems these fixes only make the squiggly go away, but the underlying problem still exists.

Comment: I went ahead and submitted a bug:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/848331/visual-studio-must-be-restarted-after-every-build.html